# Adding chars to a string

Tags: java, string, char

```
import java.util.Random;

public class PasswordRandomizer {
    // Define the variables
    private Random random = new Random();
    private int passwordLength;
    private String password = "";

    public PasswordRandomizer(int length) {
        // Initialize the variable
        this.passwordLength = length;
    }

    public String createPassword() {
        // write code that returns a randomized password
        for(int i = 0; i < this.passwordLength; i++){
            int j = random.nextInt();
            char symbol = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(j);
            this.password = this.password + symbol; 
        }
        return this.password;
    }
}
```

How can I add chars to a string, I tried this but I get this error:

> "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -414383904".

Comment: Wouldn't that just print out if i = 5 "abcde", I found one mistake that I didnt set the limit of the random number, that gives some errors, but it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's because [`random.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29) return a value between -2,147,483,648 and 2,147,483,647.

What you want is `random.nextInt("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".length())`

I would also assign `"abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"` to a constant.

```
private final static String ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";

Char randomChar = ALPHABET.charAt(random.nextInt(ALPHABET.length()));
```

Comment: It is actually the range [-2,147,483,648, 2,147,483,647]

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is not the concatenation but the random generator

```
int j = random.nextInt();
char symbol = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(j);
```

You need to use `nextInt` with a range bound

Answer (score 1):

Your are using `Random.nextInt` without any bound. This method return any integer of the 2^32 possibilities. Use the bounded `Random.nextInt("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".length())`

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
int j = random.nextInt(26);
```

The possible values will be contain between 0 and 25, included, that will match your alphabet indexes.

Answer (score 1):

This is the problem:

```
int j = random.nextInt();
char symbol = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".charAt(j);
```

The `charAt` method requires that its argument is within the bounds of the string - you're just using a random integer from [`Random.nextInt()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt--) which could have *any* `int` value:

> Returns the next pseudorandom, uniformly distributed int value from this random number generator's sequence. The general contract of nextInt is that one int value is pseudorandomly generated and returned. All 2<sup>32</sup> possible int values are produced with (approximately) equal probability.

You should use something like:

```
private static String final ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
...   
int j = random.nextInt(ALPHABET.length());
char symbol = ALPHABET.charAt(j);
```

That way you know that `j` will be within the bounds of the string (i.e. `0 <= j < ALPHABET.length()`).

There are other things I'd change about your code though:

- There's no need to use string concatenation here
- There's no need to use an instance variable for `Random` (currently each password you generate will be longer than the previous one)
- I'd use final fields
- I'd use `SecureRandom` instead of `Random` for password generation
- I'd make the class final
- I'd allow the alphabet of characters to be passed in

So:

```
public final class PasswordRandomizer {
    private static final String DEFAULT_ALPHABET = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
    private final Random random = new SecureRandom();
    private final String alphabet;
    private final int passwordLength;

    public PasswordRandomizer(int length) {
        this(length, DEFAULT_ALPHABET);
    }

    public PasswordRandomizer(int length, String alphabet) {
        // TODO: Arguvment validation
        this.passwordLength = length;
        this.alphabet = alphabet;
    }

    public String createPassword() {
        char[] chars = new char[passwordLength];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.passwordLength; i++){
            chars[i] = alphabet.charAt(random.nextInt(alphabet.length());
        }
        return new String(chars);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the code [random.nextInt()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Random.html#nextInt%28%29) create a value more than the length of the characters in "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".

Use a value between 0 and 25 . Use **`random.nextInt(25);`** instead of random.nextInt();